# Access RestWebservice by passing parameter through URL

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, url, jersey

I am trying to pass parameter required in rest method via `URL` in `Jersey+Spring`.

this is my service class.

```
@Path("/find")
public class DownLoadService {

    @Autowired
    TransactionWork transactionDownload;

    @POST
    @Path("/bring")
    public Response GetFile(String uid) {
        String result = transactionDownload.BringFile(uid);
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }

}
```

I am trying to access via URL

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/rest/find/bring'parameter for method getFile??'
```

I don't know is it possible or not.

*(I am using this first time may be silly question)*

*NOTE:I am accessing this service easily in servlet and working fine.*

Comment: `I don't know is it possible or not.` what happens when you try it?

Comment: 405 method not allowed.

Comment: OK- that's because GET isn't implemented on the service and by entering that url in a browser (I assume that is how you access it) you perform a GET request

Comment: yes i am able to access service methods which don't have parameters but I want to pass parameter via URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for long I found this way

```
    @GET
    @Path("/bring/{withUID}")
    public Response GetFile(@PathParam("withUID") String uid) {
        String result = transactionDownload.BringFile(uid);
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
```

Now I am able to access the service in this way.

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/my/bring/AB
                                                   ^
                                                   parameter I passed to method
```

**Ready to learn other way to do the same thing.**

Comment: What do you mean by 'better answer'? Despite the fact that your url parts are quite strange named this is the way to do it if you enter the restfull road.

Comment: @DirkLachowski Yeap I figured it out after posting the question but before that i don't know how to do it, well I don't know but there may be any other way to implement the same thing _(I guess)_

Comment: The way is ok, but you should really rethink your resource names. The whole thing about using a RESTful interface is to have meaningful names for your resources. To stay with your code example i suppose you have some sort of a transaction resource. Each transaction is identified by an uuid and has (among others?) a file payload. So a possible url could be `/transaction/<uuid>/filePayload`. If you call this with a `GET` you have a natural semantic of getting a transaction payload. You can read on about that in https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @DirkLachowski Okay in that sense yes I agree and thanks for the Link.